# SED to find and delete complex string between two strings

Tags: unix, replace, command-line, sed

I am trying to delete a complex string that begins and ends with a flag ( //###--X--### ) throughout a multiple files. I am able to detect the files that contain the code, but my command does not seem to execute the deletion of the string.

My command:

```
find . -iname "*.php" -print -exec sed -i -e '/^\/\###--X--###/,/^\/\/###--X--###/d' '{}' \;
```

example file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5drgnrbe4sgmkqo/indexdummy.php?dl=0

Am I overlooking something?

Thank you!

Comment: Does the command `sed -i -e '/^\/\###--X--###/,/^\/\/###--X--###/d'` itself work to you? Also, can you provide some sample files to see if this is a multiline pattern or not?

Comment: The command itself does not seem to work. I'm attaching a dummy file that has the same line endings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first sed pattern is missing a slash (that is why it does not match):

```
^\/\/###--X--###
```

Deleting from patter to pattern over a range of lines:

```
sed '/^\/\/###--X--###/,/^\/\/###--X--###/d'
```

Result:

```
<?php
?>
```

Is that what you expected? Removing your debug code?

```
find . -iname "*.php" -print -exec sed -i '/^\/\/###--X--###/,/^\/\/###--X--###/d' {} \;
```